# Understanding Fixed Regressors and Conditional Expectation on Fixed Regressors $E(Y|X_i)$

Tags: econometrics, conditional-expectation

I'm having trouble with the statistical idea of a ***fixed regressor***, it seems that our $X_i's$ are not treated as random variables, but we are still able to meaningfully condition $Y$ on them in a way that we couldn't if $X_i$ was just the constant $c$. The fixed regressor seems to be occupying a middle ground between a random variable and a constant. I have scoured the forums for all the questions related to this but have been unable to come to a conclusion.

- I think part of my confusion might stem from different econometrics books loose definition of the simple regression e.g. some use $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i$, and make no mention of $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i = E(Y|X_i)$.
- I think the mixed use between capital letters $Y, X$ and lowercase $y, x$ across texts is also not helping. (Given the very specific random variable vs observed value use in statistics generally).
- I think i'm also getting slightly confused as to when subscript i refers to a fixed value e.g. $X_i$ vs what i assume is a particular but still random value e.g. $Y_i$

Let's take our hypothetical population regression as $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i$, where $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i = E(Y|X_i)$ and $X_i$ is fixed, $E(u_i) = E(u_i|X_i) = 0$

**1) What does it mean to take conditional expectation on a fixed $X_i$?**

- Are we saying $E(Y|X = X_i)$? i.e. $E(Y|X = x)$ where $X_i = x$ an observed value
- i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_{Y|X}(y|X_i) dy$ where $f_{Y|X}(y|X_i) = \frac{f_{Y, X}(y, X_i)}{f_{X}(X_i)}$
- But then if we are told our regressor $X$ is non-random how can we give it a distribution?

**2) How do we take the expectation of $Y_i$ in this form?**

$E(Y_i) = E[E(Y|X_i)+u_i]$

- If $X_i$ were stochastic we would get $E(Y_i) = E(E(Y|X_i)) + E(u_i) = E(Y)$
- If $X_i$ is non-stochastic then
  $E(Y|X_i)$ is just a constant? $E(Y_i) = E(E(Y|X_i)) = E(Y|X_i)$
- **However, [Gujarati & Porter's Basic Econometrics 5th edition](https://ucanapplym.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/RGU/notifications/E_learning/0nline_study/Basic-Econometrics-5th-Ed-Gujarati-and-P.pdf)
  Page 34-35 goes to great lengths to highlight why this isn't the case.**
- But then in what feels like a contradiction on page 40 footnote 8 (Screenshot below) they mention "*Note that $E(Y|X_i)$, once the value of $X_i$ is fixed is treated as a constant."*
- They seem to avoid this issue by taking the conditional expectation rather than non-conditional expectation.

$Y_i = E(Y|X_i) + u_i$

$E(Y_i | X_i) = E(E(Y|X_i)|X_i) + E(u_i | X_i) = E(Y|X_i) + 0$

**3) Understanding $Y$ vs $Y_i$**

- Is the random variable $Y$ fully defined by the fandom process $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + u$ of which particular values are written as $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + u_i$?
- Is this analogous to how we might say a sample of $Z_1...Z_n$ from a random variable $Z$ but where $Z_1...Z_n$ are still random until they become observed values $z_1...z_n$.
- If so given that $X$ and hence $\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i$ is completely non stochastic how would we define this probability distribution $Y = f(u; X, \beta_0, \beta_1)$ I don't think this is correct because $X$ isn't really a parameter, but it's also not a random variable? So again i don't know how to deal with the ***fixed regressor***.
- When authors write $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + u_i$ using lower case $y_i, x_i$ generally are they referring to particular observed values or not e.g. [Chapter 2 p.g. 27 Woolridge](https://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The $X$s are *not* treated as random variables.

Take the formulation $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+U_i$ (I am changing $x$ to lowercase to emphasise it is not a random variable, and $U$ to uppercase to emphasise it is). There are only two random variables - $U_i$ (usually assumed to be a Gaussian$(0,\sigma^2)$, and $Y_i$ - a Gaussian$(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i, \sigma^2)$ by definition.

> But then if we are told our regressor $x$ is non-random how can we give it a distribution?

Example: if you have a random variable $A$ defined as $A=B+2$, where $B\sim \text{Gaussian}(0, 1)$, what is the distribution of $A$?

Now, apply the same logic to $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+U_i$, keeping in mind what is random, and what is not.

^ This also answers your second question.

Regarding the subscript $i$, you can just think of it as "some value". E.g. if you have $n$ data points total, $i$ can refer to any one of those $n$ points. So $Y_1$ is the first, $Y_2$ the second, ..., $Y_i$ the $i$-th. There's not really such thing as $Y$ in this case, it's more just notational laziness.

As a more concrete example, let's say we're regressing weight $Y$ against height $x$. It is true that $X$ has some distribution. But it doesn't matter what that distribution is, because a linear regression model specifies the distribution of $Y$ *given* the predictors. So the model says "given a person is 170cm tall, what is their weight? Given a person is 153cm tall, what is their weight?" etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will digest and get back if i have any comments!

Comment: The thing that is confusing me about your answer, is when you say A = B + 2, isn't that analogy just proving that Y has a distribution? Which I understand. What's confusing me is that we condition on X, i.e. E(Y|X), but if x were a constant this would make no sense, but X is also not a random variable so what is going on? i.e to take the conditional expectation (conditional on X) X must have a distribution for this to make sense... Thanks in advance if you're able to provide any more insight

Comment: Linear models are always modelling $E[Y|X]$, or more explicitly, $E[Y|X=x]$. Since we are conditioning on $X$, this means $X$ is _known_ and not a random variable. It doesn't matter how $X$ is distributed, because in the context of linear modelling $X$ is always known to be a value, and thus can be treated as a constant.

Comment: If we were modelling say $Y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + U_i$ where $X$ was _not_ conditioned on, that would be another case. But $X$ is always known in linear modelling.